# why does implementing callbacks (via target/selector or blocks) to my CCSequence crash my app?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I am trying to remove a sprite off of my main game layer after the sprite itself is done animating...  To do achieve this, I first attempted to pass a block into the sprite object's CCSequence like this:

```
#Game.m
// some method
    [self.spriteMan zoomAwayWithBlock:{[self destroySpriteMan];}];
    [self createNewSpriteMan];
}

-(void)destroySpriteMan {
    [self removeChild:self.spriteMan cleanup:YES];
}

#SpriteMan.m
-(void)zoomAwayWithBlock:(void(^)())block {
    [self runAction:[CCSequence actions: [CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:2.0f scale:1.0f],
                     [CCCallFuncN actionWithBlock:block],
                     nil]];
}
```

I wondered if somehow the binding of self.spriteMan was getting messed up do to [self createNewSpriteMan] being called prior to the animation completing....  So I stored spriteMan in a tempSpriteMan variable prior to calling it, and attempting to removeChild on  tempSpriteMan.....  both results in a crash immediately.

I then rewrote this to use selectors and targets:

```
#game.m
[self.spriteMan zoomAwayWithSelector:@selector(destroySpriteMan:) target:self];

-(void)destroySpriteMan:(SpriteMan *)spriteMan {
    [self removeChild:spriteMan cleanup:YES];
}

#SpriteMan.m
-(void)zoomAwayWithSelector:(SEL)sel target:(id)target {
    [self runAction:[CCSequence actions: [CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:2.0f scale:1.0f],
                     [CCCallFuncN actionWithTarget:target selector:sel],
                     nil]];
}
```

same result.. crash every time......  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This discussion seems like it might be relevant:  http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/6818

Comment: post crash message from console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Aroth pointed out, the answer lies in this topic:
http://cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/6818

It shows a solution to the problem, putting this into the array of actions solved the problem for me:

```
[CCCallFuncO actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(removeFromParentAndCleanup:) object:[CCNode node]].
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add category to CCNode with method

```
- (void) removeFromParentWithCleanupYes
{
    [self removeFromParentWithCleanup:YES];
}
```

then just make sequences like this

```
id sequence = [CCSequence actions: action1, 
                                   action2, 
                                   ..., 
                                   [CCCallFunc actionWithTarget: target selector:@selector(removeFromParentWithCleanupYes)], 
                                   nil];
[target runAction: sequence];
```

it is not very elegant, but it should work.

Or you can create your own simple action, which will remove it's target from parent.